# I clicked wrong buttons on VScode

Tags: visual-studio-code

[vscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2KuO.png)

I clicked ctrl+shift+"-" ctrl plus shift plus minus and vscode got small how can i turn it back

Comment: `ctrl+shift+"-"` is zoomOut, `ctrl+shift+"="` is zoomIn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ctrl+shift+"=" and Ctrl+shift+"-" didn't work. But i found a way, settings>Search "zoom">change zoom level